# React: how to prevent api calls in ComponentDidMount and in ComponentDidUpdate override each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, race-condition, lifecycle, fetch-api

In `componentDidMount` I am fetching data using a `Redux` action, for example:

```
componentDidMount() {
   let parameter = some code;
   this.props.getAction(parameter).then(r => {
     if(r.type.endsWith('SUCCESS')){
       this.setState({cList: r.payload.data.data})
     }
   }
}
```

and then, in the `componentDidUpdate` I need to fetch again data, when the parameters inside the function change (I am using `lodash`):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   if(!isEqual(this.props.parameter, prevProps.parameter){
     let parameter = some code;
     if(r.type.endsWith('SUCCESS')){
       this.setState({cList: r.payload.data.data})
     }
   }
}
```

The problem is that if the `Promise` in the `componentDidUpdate` returns the result before the `Promise` in `componentDidMount`, when I have my parameter changed in the component, the data shown is wrong; it is still showing the data from `componentDidMount` and not from the new action calls in the `componentDidUpdate`.

I hope everything is clear.

How can I avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: CDU  is *not called for the initial render* so wonder how it conflicts with CDM?

Comment: Can you please create a codesandbox or codepen for this ? 
How your parameter is getting changed without mounting component ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep an instance variable `lastRequestId` in your component to track which promise is running, something like this :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.lastRequestId = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let parameter = "some code";
    this.lastRequestId = 'ON_MOUNT_REQUEST';
    this.props.getAction(parameter).then(r => {
      if(r.type.endsWith('SUCCESS') && this.lastRequestId === 'ON_MOUNT_REQUEST'){
        this.setState({cList: r.payload.data.data})
      }
    })
  } 

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(!isEqual(this.props.parameter, prevProps.parameter)) {
      let parameter = "some code";
      this.lastRequestId = 'ON_UPDATE_REQUEST';
      this.props.getAction(parameter).then(r => {
        if(r.type.endsWith('SUCCESS') && this.lastRequestId === 'ON_UPDATE_REQUEST'){
          this.setState({cList: r.payload.data.data})
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```